# Is IHierarchicalEnumerable the prefered way of dealing with hierarchical data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I'm building an asp.net mvc app, I want to build up an hierarchical structure, is IHierarchicalEnumerable and IHierarchyData the best way to implement a hierarchical structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two interfaces were written with ASP.NET WebForms in mind (they are not strongly-typed, so that WebForms DataSources can work with hierarchies of arbitrary object types). For an MVC application, you will probably be better off writing your own classes to describe the data hierarchy.